# Weighted graph in Neo4j

Tags: java, graph, neo4j

I have a Neo4j instance running. I have relationships which are weighted. One such example is representing all places in the world, and having a distance between each place.

Now it seems easy to create a relationship between two nodes, A and B:

```
Relationship relationship = A.createRelationshipTo(B, Relations.Knows );
```

But what about actual strength of the relationship. Theres been a suggestion on here as :

```
create a-[:`KNOWS_0.34`]->b
```

This works, but isn't a particularly great solution, particularly if you wanted to calculate a shortest distance dependent on the weights.

Is there anyway of doing this and storing the relationship int or float?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't aware of this, but seems you can set additional properties when creating a `Relationship`:

```
Relationship relAB = createRelationship( nodeA, nodeC, "length", 2d );
```

Comment: Neo4j is a property graph, this means you can have an arbitrary number of properties on both nodes and relationships

Comment: do you know what functionality there is for paths, whereby I want a path from one node to another, being the shortest and yet using the biggest weights?

Comment: You could retrieve all the shortest paths between the two nodes, and then compare their weight: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-match.html#_shortest_path

Comment: This function finds, the shortest path (singular not plural :( )

Comment: Well, you should have read the whole section :). You have both 'allShortestPaths' and 'shortestPath'

Answer (score 3):

It's a good approach to use a weight property on your relationship!

Take a look at [Graph Algorithm examples](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-graph-algo.html) in the Neo4j tutorial pages. It describes various ways to find shortest paths using weighted relationships e.g. using Dijkstra or A* algorithms. A great dijkstra example can be found [here](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/java-dijkstra).